# sbt-scoverage exclude syntax

Tags: regex, scala, sbt, scoverage

I just started using scoverage for the first time. It's working great for me now, but I encountered a problem with the syntax excluding a package.

When my package structure is the following:

```
- com
   - project
      - core
        - excluded
        - notExcluded
```

What should I add to my build.sbt to exclude the package: *excluded*?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of following should work for you:

`coverageExcludedPackages := ".*exclude.*"`

`coverageExcludedPackages := "com\\.project\\.core\\.exclude.*"`

https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage

Comment: Thank you! The used syntax is now clear for me, I didn't understand it from their github.

Comment: Adding comment as, as a noob I was not able to find coverageExcludedPackages directly, but it should be as below
**ScoverageKeys.coverageExcludedPackages := "com\\.foo\\.bar.*"**

Comment: how do I exclude a file